# Ubuntu 16.04 - Genymotion: /dev/hw_random not found

Tags: android, genymotion, ubuntu-16.04

I install `Genymotion` on the `Ubuntu 16.04 64Bit`. I created a virtual emulator for Android 6.0 then I run this emulator but emulator is disappearing and the emulator is running background. I checked the emulator on the `VirtualBox` and I saw this issue:
[image: ISSUE]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue:
**`System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers`** :
[image]
Then you click `Apply Changes` button and you restart your pc.

I don't know reason of the issue, open source driver is not running for `Genymotion` but NVIDIA is running.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, but this is not my solution

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue as in the image but i am using Windows 10 and the version of Genymotion is 3.0.1, so the problem was that my graphics card no longer matches Genymotion requirements. So simple solution was that I had downgrade Genymotion to 2.12.2.

https://dl.genymotion.com/releases/genymotion-2.12.2/genymotion-2.12.2.exe

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your install directory and delete the libdrm.so.2, then restart.

Use command:

```
cd /genymotion/install/directory
mv libdrm.so.2 libdrm.so.2_bk
```

And then restart.

Here is the reference: [Genymotion is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841985/genymotion-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

For those who struggled with this problem, I just could not get it to solve - tried different versions of virtualbox to see what is compatible with genymotion etc

Finally I directly downloaded and android vdi from here 
http://www.osboxes.org/android-x86/

and installed it as in

https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/importing-a-vdi-in-virtualbox

wwhew ... that worked

Hope that helps

Answer (score -2):

Update your genymotion and Virtualbox... 
this way fix problem

Comment: Do you have any information to say that this problem has been fixed in any update?

Comment: i have tried on 2 OS ubuntu 16.04 and fedora 26 with same problem but after updated genymotion and vbox ... genymotion is running normally.. maybe the updating is fix this problem

Comment: Genymotion version 2.10.0 and Virtualbox v. 5.1.26