# Ubuntu 17.04 - Genymotion: emulator blank screen & Virtualbox: /dev/hw_random not found

Tags: genymotion

I installed `Genymotion` on `Ubuntu 17.04`,and create a new virtual emulator. And it can run normally. Today I open it again, but the emulator is ***blank screen***,like this:
[image]

When I check it on `VirtualBox`, I found this:
[image]

Someone has answered it, but is not my solution:
[ubuntu-16-04-genymotion-dev-hw-random-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322338/ubuntu-16-04-genymotion-dev-hw-random-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

Please update your Genymotion and Virtualbox...
i haved same problem, but after update app, my genymotion is running normally..